# Segue from an Editing Accessory

Tags: ios, uitableview, segue

In Xcode, when I try to connect a view controller with a segue, I get a choice of fire the segue upon selection of the table cell or from the cell's accessory.  How do I create the segue to fire from the cell's *editing* accessory (which isn't visible on the storyboard)?

Comment: Hook the segue from view controller to destination controller. And call `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` manually when you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Add `accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath` Delegate method of tableview and than add segue code in that delegate method.

```
// Tap on row accessory
    - (void) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath{
           [self performSegueWithIdentifier:"MyVC" sender:self];
    }
```

And if you are using navigationcontroller than

```
// Tap on row accessory
    - (void) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath{
           ViewController * vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyVC"];
           [[self navigationController] pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
    }
```

This methods called when you tap on accessory button but if you want this on row tapped than use `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` Method